# JTextField keep filling the space of the JMenuBar

Tags: java, jmenubar

Im trying to add buttons and textfields into my jMenuBar and even after I set the JTextField's PreferredSize, the JTextField keeps on filling the space on my JMenuBar.

Note: this JMenuBar was added by using this method -

```
public static void setJPanelMenuBar(JPanel parent, JPanel child, JMenuBar menuBar) {
        parent.removeAll();
        parent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JRootPane root = new JRootPane();
        parent.add(root, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        root.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        root.getContentPane().add(child);
        parent.putClientProperty("root", root);  //if you need later
    }
```

The code allows me to add a JMenuBar in a JPanel.

now on to the JMenuBar code.

```
JMenuBar x = jMenuBar1;

        x.removeAll();

        JTextField searchBar = txtsearch;
        JTextField searchBar2 = new JTextField();

        searchBar2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,20));

        x.add(lblsearch);
        x.add(searchBar);
        x.add(btnSearch);
        x.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        x.add(searchBar2);
```

NOTE: the `jMenuBar1`,`lblsearch`,`txtsearch`, and `btnSearch` was created using NetBeans.

to test this, I added another JTextField called `searchBar2` and set the Preferred Size but both keeps on occupying the space left in the JMenuBar even after I added the Box Glue.

Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

From the [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) tutorial:

> When a BoxLayout lays out components from top to bottom, it tries to size each component at the component's preferred height. If the vertical space of the layout does not match the sum of the preferred heights, then **BoxLayout tries to resize the components to fill the space.** The components either grow or shrink to fill the space, with BoxLayout honoring the minimum and maximum sizes of each of the components. Any extra space appears at the bottom of the container.

(Emphasis mine)

Obviously the same applies to widths in a horizontal box.  In my opinion, the above should be in the actual javadoc for BoxLayout, but it's not.

In your case, the easiest solution is to remove that explicit call to setPreferredSize, and instead set each JTextField's maximum size to match its preferred size:

```
searchBar.setMaximumSize(searchBar.getPreferredSize());
searchBar2.setMaximumSize(searchBar2.getPreferredSize());
```

BoxLayout tries to respect minimum and maximum sizes.